# Adding DataGridView to ActiveReports 3

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, activereports

I need to add a DataGridView to an ActiveReports 3 file. When I add the control its not recognized as a DataGridView but rather a custom control. Can anyone help me get around this?

Comment: Why are you trying to add a DataGridView control to your report and not use the native ActiveReport control (eg. TextBox control)? The entire purpose of ActiveReports is for you to bind your data collection and it will handle the iterating and rendering of that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast CustomControl.Control to DataGridView to access the object programmatically from the format event of the control containing the section. There is an example of doing this in the [CustomControl.Control property's documentation topic](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ARNET3/ActiveReports3_start.htm?ActiveReports3~DataDynamics.ActiveReports.CustomControl~Control.html). Note that in that topic, it uses ChartFX, but you'll be using DataGridView.

However, @LordHits comment about using DataGridView in a report is a good one. Normally, you'd just want to connect the report to the same data source and use the same query and let the report get the data. You can also bind the report to a System.Data.DataSet easily as well. See the help topic ["How-To Section > Binding Reports to a Data Source > Using a Dataset" in the ActiveReports 3 User Guide](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ARNET3/ActiveReports3_start.htm?ar3tskUsingaDataSet.html).

```
Scott Willeke
GrapeCity
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I am new to reports  so at the time of this posting i was pretty unaware of its data handling capabilities. Thanks for pointing it out.