# Active Reports PDF Generation

Tags: c#, asp.net, activereports

I've inherited a project that uses Active Reports.  I'm required to basically create a simple pdf that holds data that's in a DataGrid on one of my ASP.NET pages.

I've only found a single walkthrough on the DataDynamics website and it only applies to users of VS2003 and VS2005.

The report I need doesn't need to be interactive.  I don't need to use Document and Page events.  I just need to take what I have in a DataTable (which is bound to my grid) and create a pdf file, which will be available for download.

Is there a straightforward way to create this simple, static report with ActiveReports?  Thanks.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244922/adding-datagridview-to-active-report-3 . Abhishek's is pretty good below, but there is also good information at the other question too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

kmarks,

You can indeed do this very easily, you can use the same DataTable as a datasource for report by setting the datasource property of the report to the DataTable.Then you just need to add an ActiveReports TextBox control to the Details section of the report and then set its DataField property to a column name in the datatable to bind a field from the datatable to the TextBox control.You can do this either at design time or in the code behind

After you have done this,just create an instance of the report,call the Run the method on this instance and then export the report document to PDF.

I would also suggest you to go through the following link which can help you achieve the same.

http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/arWLKCustomWebExporting.html

You can also download a sample application which converts a DataGrid to PDF report using Active Reports form here

ftp://ftp.fpoint.com/ActiveReports/Samples/GridToPdf.zip

Regards,

Abhishek Dutta

Grapecity